# What is the method to set the text for a QTreeWidget's header?

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

I've checked the documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html) and I can't seem to find a method for setting the text of a QTreeWidget's title or header.

Without setting the title QTreeWidget automatically uses the number '1' in my code. An example of what it looks like outputted is below. I'm presuming QTreeWidget has a method for this and I just can't find it.

[image: QTreeWidget example]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're looking for [setHeaderLabel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#setHeaderLabel).

Note that the documentation says it adds a new column, so if your view already has column 0 with text "1", you may instead have to do the following:

```
if(QTreeWidgetItem* header = treeWidget->headerItem()) {
  header->setText(0, "My Text");
} else {
  treeWidget->setHeaderLabel("My Text");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is an another method to set header texts

```
QStringList headerLabels;
headerLabels.push_back(tr("text1"));
headerLabels.push_back(tr("text2"));
headerLabels.push_back(tr("text3"));
..
headerLabels.push_back(tr("textN"));

treeWidget->setColumnCount(headerLabels.count());
treeWidget->setHeaderLabels(headerLabels);
```