# Set the header text of a QTreeView header

Tags: qt, header, treeview, settext

I have the same problem as:

[What is the method to set the text for a QTreeWidget's header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943866/what-is-the-method-to-set-the-text-for-a-qtreewidgets-header)

with one difference: I'm using a treeView, not tree widget, so the answer there didn't help.

I couldn't find in the documentation any instructions how to it.

So - how can I set the header text of a QTreeView?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It may be done in your model class that probably inherits [QStandardItemModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html).

Typically, you would call:

```
QStandardItemModel::setHorizontalHeaderLabels ( const QStringList & labels )
```

for text only, or

```
 QStandardItemModel::setHorizontalHeaderItem ( int column, QStandardItem * item )
```

if more customization is needed in the header items.

Answer (score 0):

Ah... anyone getting frustrated with this with PyQt5 might like to try this:

```
self.ui.treeView.setHeaderHidden( False )
```

Comment: This is not what is asked